# How can I calculate time constant and charge time of RRC circuit?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, analog, delay

This circuit is part of my time delay circuit. I want to calculate exact value of delay time. Please help me.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fB1tM2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Find the thevenin equivalent of the source applied to the input with R1 and R2. Now you have the standard RC filter and you can evaluate it the usual way.

Comment: If the input is a true voltage source then the time constant is R2C1 and has nothing to do with R1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two time constants here.  One is when the input is driven and the other when it is open.

Probably the input is driven high, then left to float low.  When the input is driven, you assume it has 0 impedance to ground.  Note that this impedance is parallel to R1.  What is R1//0?  When the input is open-circuit, then it has infinite impdance to ground.  The effective resistance seen at the top of C1 to ground should be obvious in that case.